# Managing locally compiled software

Tags: package-management, compiling, non-root-user

I have to run a C++ software on a computer where I only have user access. There are a bunch of dependencies that I have to have installed first before I can run the program I am interested in:

[image]

All of use GNU Autotools and I have to pass a couple specific options to `./configure`. The compiler is also non standard (it cross compiles for BlueGene/Q). In order to have some reproducibility, I have written a Bash script that fetches the source, compiles it and installes it into `$HOME/local`:

```
base_flags="-O2 -finline-limit=50000 -Wall -Wpedantic $color_flags"

if ! [[ -d gmp-6.1.1 ]]; then
    wget https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/gmp-6.1.1.tar.xz
    tar -xf gmp-6.1.1.tar.xz
fi

pushd gmp-6.1.1
cflags="$base_flags"
cxxflags="$base_flags"
if ! [[ -f Makefile ]]; then
    ./configure $base_configure CFLAGS="$cflags"
fi
if ! [[ -f build-succeeded ]]; then
    nice make $make_smp_flags
    make install
    touch build-succeeded
    pushd $prefix/lib
    rm -f *.so *.so.*  # Force static linkage.
    popd
fi

# Similar stanzas for the other projects.
```

On my personal computer where I have root access, I build RPM packages for all the software that I want to have installed, let the RPMs build on the Open Build Service hosted by the openSUSE project and install those with Ansible. Working on the remote computer feels like Linux from Scratch or so, I cannot upgrade or uninstall something and I have to remember the versions and flags used.

All I can think of is trying to emulate RPM packages by setting `DESTDIR` and `--prefix` in such a way that I can TAR the build products and then un-TAR that into `$HOME/local`. Then I would write some uninstaller/updater which lists the archive contents and removes those files from `$HOME/local`.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Ask the sysadmin to install the packages?

Comment: No, that does not work. They would have to install that system wide and I there are no official RPM packages. Also I need to tinker with the software, so going through the admins would mean a lot of latency in the edit-compile-run cycle.